# android com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android

```
 public void sendPostUser(JSONObject jsonObject ,final postSuccess postSuccess)  {

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    String m = jsonObject.get("success").toString();
                    if(m != null){
                        postSuccess.success(true);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                postSuccess.success(false);
            }
        });
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(18000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
    }
```

this is my code , i send JSONObject to server php , But this error is displayed :
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value

```
    <?php
    $json=file_get_contents('php://input');
    $userInfo=json_decode($json);
    $title=$userInfo->title;
    $content=$userInfo->content;
    include 'DatabaseManager';
    $databaseManager=new DatabaseManager();
    $databaseManager->addPostUser($title,$content);


function addPostUser($title,$content){
            $dbConection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",DatabaseManager::DATABASE_NAME);
            $sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO posts(title,content) VALUES('$title','$content')";
            if (mysqli_connect($dbConection,$sqlCommand)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: post the response that is generated !!

Comment: response is a JSONObject. Why you are converting it to string and then as used it to initialize JSONObject

Comment: Show your `PHP` code for `addPostUser`